# Rendering Component Returned Component Completely In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm creating an app and I need to render a form element multiple times with some of the variable names changed around. Unfortunately, I'm having some issues where not all of the code is being returned from the component. I've taken out some of the variable declarations to make this easier to read.

**Primary Component**

```
export default function StrengthLog() {
   
    return (
        <Container id="strengthContainer">
            <SelectMovements />
            <Form>
            {
                movement.map(movement => {
                    const checked = movement[1].triggered
                    if (checked){
                        return <StrengthForm props={movement}/>
                    }
                })
            }
            <Button content='submit'>Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

**Component being returned**

```
export default function StrengthForm({props}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
                {               
                    props[1].triggered
                    ? (
                        setsArray.map(item => {
                            return <Group widths='equal'>
                            <Select fluid label='Reps' placeholder='Select Reps' options={repOptions} name={`${liftVarName}-rep-1`}/>
                            <Input fluid placeholder='Enter Weight' label='Weight' name={`${liftVarName}-weight-1`}/>
                            <Button className="addSet">+</Button>
                            <Button className="deleteSet">x</Button>
                            </Group>
                        })
                    )
                    : console.log('Thing')
                 }
        </div>
    )
}
```

What's happening is that it's returning the `<h1>` of `StrengthForm` but it's not returning the other information contained within the curly braces.

Comment: Are you sure that `props[1].triggered` evaluate to true ?

Comment: Just did a `console.log(props[1].triggered)` and it does return as `true`

Comment: what is `setsArray` variable? from where is it coming from?

Comment: `const setsArray = new Array(props[1].sets)` where `props[1].sets` is always set to 3 for now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was declaring `setsArray` as `const setsArray = new Array(props[1].sets)` which gives me `StrengthForm.js:9 (4) [empty × 4]` in the console. I suspected because the array actually had no content that I needed to add something there so I commented my initial declaration and did this instead.

```
    const setsArray = (() => {
        const emptyArray = []
        for(let i = 0; i <= props[1].sets; i++) {
            emptyArray.push(' ');
        }
        return emptyArray;
    })();
```

```
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
                {               
                    props[1].triggered
                    ? (
                        setsArray.map(() => {
                            return <>
                            <Group widths='equal'>
                            <Select fluid label='Reps' placeholder='Select Reps' options={repOptions} name={`${liftVarName}-rep-1`}/>
                            <Input fluid placeholder='Enter Weight' label='Weight' name={`${liftVarName}-weight-1`}/>
                            <Button className="addSet">+</Button>
                            <Button className="deleteSet">x</Button>
                            </Group>
                            </>
                        })
                        
                    )
                    : console.log('Thing')
                 }
        </div>
    )
```

Everything popped up after I changed it to this!